# can anyone tell me from where this block is coming in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to find the block of which the referred section in the image is loading. Please help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwTJb.png

Comment: either from stores-> configuration -> general -> store information

Comment: or from stores->configruation -> sales tab -> shipping methods

Comment: thank you for your helping but actually i want change the message as shown in the image in bracket portion so want to know the physical path location from where this part is coming..thank you

Comment: just enable template hints in admin and check frontend pls.

Answer (score 0):

That info is being rendered from:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html
```

or

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html
```

Comment: No we cant confirm it. if the theme is already overriding this file.

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar then just look at theme, or override it using require-config.js